# Product Edit page is taking lots of time to load

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on woocommerce project Where I have used lots of custom fields to create a product using "Advanced Product Fields Extended for WooCommerce" Plugin but its taking losts of time to render fields on page and because of this browser gets unresponsive below is the screenshot. I have increased memory limit also but does not work. So Please have a look screenshot and provide me any solution for it.

Below is the screeshot:-

1. https://prnt.sc/14upj4m
2. https://prnt.sc/14uq135

Answer (score 0):

Install a plugin called [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) on your staging website where you are having this issue.

You can read the complete documentation here : https://querymonitor.com/

[image: Query monitor]

Load the page where you see the issue. You will find the following number in the admin bar showing.

- Page generation time in seconds
- Total memory usage in kilobytes
- Total time taken by SQL queries in seconds
- Total number of SQL queries

Clicking on that you can find Queries. Clicking on that will show you deatils on which queries are taking maximum time.

You can then debug and find the source of the problem which needs to be solved.

Comment: I have used that plugin and its showing some queries which taking bit more time but those queries are coming from paid plugin which i cannot modify. Is there any way to to render product custom fields after page load

Comment: Why can't you ? Deactivate the plugin and see if the speed issue gets resolved. If not, paid plugins have support where you can report them that there plugin is causing this.